# Slide Up a div element inside a div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I slide up div id with "front" when hovering on div id with "card1"
also when the mouse pointer is not on that div, div id with "front" should slide down. Please have CSS for reference

```
   <html>
    <head>
    <style>
.cards{
    position:relative;

}
#front{
    position:absolute;  
    left:50px;
    z-index:2;
    background-color:red;
    color:white;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    border-radius:5px;
}
#back{
    position:absolute;
    left:50px;
    z-index:1;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background-color:blue;
    color:white;
    border-radius:5px;
}
</style>
   </head>
    <body>
    <div class="cards" id="card1">
                <div id="front">
                    <div class="caption" style="text-align:center;">
                        <h6><b>Hello</b></h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="back">
                        <div id="buttons">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary lis" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#hello">Description</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary lis" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#heelo1">show message</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary lis">show message</button>                               
                        </div>
                        <div id="buttons">
                            <img id="imagesLg" src="thiser.gif" alt="HelloWorld"/>
                        </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: first of, you have multiple elements with the same id `buttons`, you should never have multiple elements with the same id

Comment: please add your css also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I hope my answser will help u !**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <style>
        .cards {
            position: relative;
        }

        #front {
            position: absolute;
            left: 50px;
            z-index: 2;
            background-color: red;
            color: white;
            height: 200px;
            width: 200px;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }

        #back {
            position: absolute;
            left: 50px;
            z-index: 1;
            height: 200px;
            width: 200px;
            background-color: blue;
            color: white;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('div[id="card1"]').on('mouseover', function () {
                $('div[id="front"]').slideUp();
            });

            $('div[id="card1"]').on('mouseleave', function () {
                $('div[id="front"]').slideDown();
            });
        });
    </script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="cards" id="card1">
        <div id="front">
            <div class="caption" style="text-align:center;">
                <h6><b>Hello</b></h6>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="back">
            <div id="buttons">
                <button class="btn btn-primary lis" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#hello">Description</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary lis" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#heelo1">show message</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary lis">show message</button>
            </div>
            <div id="buttons">
                <img id="imagesLg" src="thiser.gif" alt="HelloWorld" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using javascript.

Put two event listener on '#card1'.

1. First mousein, on mousein elevate the '#front' division (you can use margin-top: -100px or anything on it),
2. And use mouseout, on mouseout put the '#front' division on its original position(margin-top: 0px)

```js
$('#card1').on('mouseenter',function(){
 $('#front').css('margin-top','-100px')
}).on('mouseout',function(){
$('#front').css('margin-top','0')
})
```

I've done it (basic implementation without any animation and stuff) using jquery.

Do leave a comment if its not clear to you.

Thanks

Comment: how can I retrieve id "card1" dynamically

Comment: You are giving the id by yourself. So why do you need to retrieve it dynamically? You already have it with you...you know whats the id

Comment: because there can be multiple div tags like card1, for example:- card2, card3 and so on.

Comment: Then do it based on class name. give all your dynamic divs a common class name maybe 'cards'. And put event listener for that class. Also if required give tow common class inside each of these divs('cards') like 'front' and 'back'. Now all you've to do is on 'mousein; of '.card', find the '.front' class  and give margin-top of -10px and then on 'mouseout' give margin-top of 0px to '.front' class.

Comment: Sure. Let me know if you face any issue.. :)

Comment: I have added slideUp animation to two div  and these two divs "cards" get slideUp at the same time, what if I want to slideUp that card which I had mouseover

Comment: then make use of 'this' variable to find the class 'fiirst' that you want to elevate.

Comment: ex: $('cards').on('click',function(){$(this).find('.first').css('margin-top','-100px')}) something like this